# installing packages in cygwin without compiling from source

Tags: emacs, cygwin, portability

I have recently installed cygwin as I want to use (and learn) emacs and make it my regular text editor (as I use Notepad++ now).

The motivation for this comes from some sites like this:
http://batsov.com/articles/2011/08/19/a-peek-at-emacs24/

Also, I want to learn the internals of linux. I tried vi but its too CUIish for my taste. So I installed cygwin (with it's default emacs 23.3). But I wanted to try emacs 24 too so I want to install it side by side with cygwin's emacs 23.3. This can be done in a linux distro by installing emacs in /opt and making symlinks. But how do I install emacs binaries in cygwin?
From where do I get such binaries.

Currently I am using 'Emacs for Windows' seperately from cygwin, but it is hard to get it in a portable format. If I manage to install it in cygwin then my whole cygwin environment can be portable.

I generally try to install softwares so that they are portable as far as possible.

Comment: also how can i set file associations for emacs?

Comment: Why use cygwin? Why not just the native Emacs build for Windows?

Comment: i want to use cygwin so that entire toolchain of unix tools on windows can be portable and i dont have to install/configure it again and again as i switch machines

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setup.exe that you used to install cygwin, to install Emacs as well.